# HTML Hyperlinks using url query strings

Tags: html, web

Some sites use hyper links like:

```
www.example.com\index.php?x=test.php

www.example.com\index.php?test.php

www.example.com\index.php?\test.php
```

instead of simply:

```
www.example.com\test.php
```

Are there any advantages of linking to other pages using query strings instead of simple hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

**When to use them**

If the order is irrelevant or if they can be combined in different ways. In many cases like pagination not all query strings are needed to get the desired result. So the are usually always optional.

**Advantages**

They do not have the encoding issues of named params and are pretty much the way all other web apps also use such volatile params. So it is the de facto standard for web apps.

With query strings the short-routed action names (usually all index actions) don’t pop up anymore as long as you don’t use passed params:

Answer (score 0):

URLs are passed in Referrer headers – if a secure page uses resources, such as javascript, images or analytics services, the URL is passed in the Referrer request header of each embedded request. Sometimes the query string parameters may be delivered to and stored by third party sites.

It can be useful wile posting a data on a webservice, or u can even pass a session ID along with the URL in query parameters provided they are encoded.

Answer (score -2):

The type of notation that you mentioned earlier is aided by the concept called url rewriting.

Many php frameworks these days use MVC architecture for code organisation into three tiers. This enhance code scalability and web application's security.

All the requests to the server are directed to index.php where they are resolved to load a particular action, thus hiding the background layout of the code.

Here test.php can be present either at the root or inside some other folder depending upon the location specified to the routing algorithms that are called in index.php